# Adding this infowindow navigational link code to my KML search code

Tags: search, dictionary, kml, kmz

I'm hoping to combine the following two codes to create a map that not only searches with a layer of KMZ on top, but also shows navigation options in the infowindow. An example of the two maps side by side can be [viewed here](http://touring-britain.heralded.co.uk/). But I want to combine the two maps into one. I've included my attempt at this at the bottom of this post - but it doesn't work.

1. Firstly, I've adapted this code for searching a map with my kmz (or kml) layered onto it and it works just fine ...

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
      }
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

    </style>
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <script>
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {lat:53.6292604,lng:-2.9380916},
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
var mapLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: "https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=zQWA66D2AmlU.kGvUUZ4wvdYo",
suppressInfoWindows:false,
preserveViewport:true });
mapLayer.setMap(map);


  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // [START region_getplaces] this was the first to cause problems
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]
}


    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY-KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. This second code works great with adding a direction link to the info window so you can drive there using your smartphone ...

```js
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8"><title>Embedded Map</title>

<style>
html, body, #map-canvas {
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<script>
var map;
var infowindow;
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {center: {lat:53.6292604,lng:-2.9380916},
zoom: 5}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var mapLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: "https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=zQWA66D2AmlU.kGvUUZ4wvdYo",
suppressInfoWindows:true,
preserveViewport:true });
mapLayer.setMap(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(mapLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
var text = kmlEvent.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
text = text + '<br><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=loc:'+kmlEvent.latLng.toUrlValue(6)+'" target="_blank">Navigate to Here</a>';
if (infowindow) { infowindow.setContent(text);
} else {
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: text});
}
infowindow.setOptions({position:kmlEvent.latLng, pixelOffset:kmlEvent.pixelOffset});
infowindow.open(map);
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script></head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body></html>
```

3. Putting the two scripts together here, it looks something like this, although this doesn't work. Any answers gratefully received about whats going wrong here please ...

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
      }
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

    </style>
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <script>
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {lat:53.6292604,lng:-2.9380916},
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
var mapLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: "https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=zQWA66D2AmlU.kGvUUZ4wvdYo",
suppressInfoWindows:false,
preserveViewport:true });
mapLayer.setMap(map);


  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // [START region_getplaces] this was the first to cause problems
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]
  var map;
var infowindow;
mapLayer.setMap(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(mapLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
var text = kmlEvent.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
text = text + '<br><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=loc:'+kmlEvent.latLng.toUrlValue(6)+'" target="_blank">Navigate to Here</a>';
if (infowindow) { infowindow.setContent(text);
} else {
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: text});
}
infowindow.setOptions({position:kmlEvent.latLng, pixelOffset:kmlEvent.pixelOffset});
infowindow.open(map);
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}


    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY-KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The posted code has a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` on the last line of the javascript.  When I remove that, [I get a map](http://jsfiddle.net/cf0uuawd/3/)

Comment: I also changed `suppressInfoWindows: false` to `suppressInfoWindows: true` on the KmlLayer.

Comment: My goodness, thank you sooooo much. I fried my brain yesterday. Really kind of you. I'll raise a glass to you next time I'm out. Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the final `}` in the javascript, it generates a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`.
2. change `suppressInfoWindows: false` to `suppressInfoWindows: true` (removes the extraneous second copy of the infowindow).

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: 53.6292604,
      lng: -2.9380916
    },
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var mapLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: "https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=zQWA66D2AmlU.kGvUUZ4wvdYo",
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  mapLayer.setMap(map);


  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // [START region_getplaces] this was the first to cause problems
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]
  var map;
  var infowindow;
  mapLayer.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(mapLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
    text = text + '<br><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=loc:' + kmlEvent.latLng.toUrlValue(6) + '" target="_blank">Navigate to Here</a>';
    if (infowindow && infowindow.setContent) {
      infowindow.setContent(text);
    } else {
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: text
      });
    }
    infowindow.setOptions({
      position: kmlEvent.latLng,
      pixelOffset: kmlEvent.pixelOffset
    });
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
</style> <title>Places Searchbox</title> <style> #target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```